# web sockets - can I send extra info about client in the moment of connecting to server using socket.connect() method

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, socket.io, webrtc

I am working on webrtc project and I have client(s) with input video stream, client that will show input stream and server. I am using webrtc and websockets. Every client is connected to signaling server. I want to know how server can know if connected client is client with input video stream or it is client that will show some streams. Can I send some extra info in the moment of connecting client side to server? Client is written in Javascript and server in Python. Maybe I can use some parameters in socket.connect() method?

Server handling connecting:

```js
@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print('Connected', sid)
    sessionIDs.append(sid)

    await sio.emit('ready', room=ROOM, skip_sid=sid)
    sio.enter_room(sid, ROOM)
```

Connecting client to server:

```js
socket.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your data as GET parameter in the websocket url, or use a differente path.

```
const socket = io("ws://localhost:3000?arg1=1&arg2=2");
// or
const socket = io("ws://localhost:3000/path1");
```

And on the [server](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/#query) to get them:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.handshake.query); // prints { x: "42", EIO: "4", transport: "polling" }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I understood what you said, but can you tell me how should server handle that request